# SteamVR + Vridge and Unity Game Development using Google Cardboard(C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality

Good day everyone. I have a problem with my game since I'm using the openvr when building my game. The **problem** is whenever I build my game as a .exe, the position of my camera from my start menu is a little bit off, what I mean is that it is not placed like in the unity editor. And the **second one** is that even if i disable my track rotation under my head gameobject it still detects the trackrotation (When built).

**So far what i had tried are:**

1.) setting the trackrotation in the script into trackrotation = false; (still didn't work)

2.) Removing the GvrHead Script from the head(Still effin rotates).

Why is that it still rotate even if I already remove the script from the head and set the trackrotation = false in the script.

or should i disable the gyroscope from my project?

I need to disable it because of the animation I have on my game. It needs to disable the trackrotation.

Someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using my 3rd party software so i did go to vridge app on my phone and disable the tracking rotation of the 3rd party software . So that solves my problem .